# Eclipse Equivalent of Visual Studio's Ctrl-Dot For Importing Classes

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, if I'm trying to use a class I have the definition for (but haven't imported into my existing file), I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and I'll see a little popup asking me which of these imported classes with the same name I want to import.

What's the equivalent of this in Eclipse?

Comment: I had the reverse question, thanks!

Comment: Ctrl-Dot doesn't work for me in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @lxx, my question was about 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Organize Imports: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for all or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> > *Import...* on a single line.

Comment: Also, when you first type the class-to-be-imported's name into the code, before you hit dot or space or anything, type Ctrl-Space and it will do the import then and there. (and the kbd tag trick doesn't work in comments).